# Array to be stored in file

Tags: php, file

I have an array that contains numbers.I have to store the numbers in file text and the numbers should be separated by comas in that text file.How can i do that in PHP?

$a is my array and "file.txt" is my file.

But when i am storing in file by

```
file_put_contents("file.txt",$a)
```

the numbers are storing without comas.

Eg: 34567 the way they are storing but i want it as 3,4,5,6,7,

Comment: Take a look at the CSV functions PHP offers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: How are you going to be using the file? You could write a .json file opposed to a .txt or you could use a CSV as @arkascha has said

Comment: @SwitchCase Writing a json encoded array notation into a file results in a text file. Not sure where you see a difference.

Comment: Depends what he is trying to do with it, e.g. using Mongo DB to store it (Might be overreaching here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **implode** to make the array number array to string then use **fopen** to create a text file and store the number in that text file.

**EX:-**

```
$contents=implode(',',$array)
$embedName = 'file path/file' . time() . ".txt";
$myFile = fopen($embedName, "w");
fwrite($myFile, $contents);
fclose($myFile);
```

I thing it will help you.